# DisplayAlert not responsive in WPF - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have added a WPF project to my existing Xamarin Forms Project. (.Net Standard 2.0). I use DisplayAlert to display pop-up messages. The message to be displayed is a long text. The text wraps in Android and UWP ( I have not tested it yet in iOS), But in WPF, the text does not wrap. I had to add \n after few words (only for WPF). Also, if I reduce the size of the window, the pop-up is cropped. The pop-up looks fine on other platforms.

Is it that 'Display Alert' is not fully supported in WPF? Is there any Standard method to display pop-ups on all platforms - Including WPF?

I had posted this question in Xamarin Forums as well but did not get an answer.

I have attached some screenshots for reference.

**The DisplayAlert issue:**

[image: Image showing the DisplayAlert issue]